# Mac OS X - get end of line in file

Tags: c++, macos, file

I try to open and read a file on Mac OS X:

```
FILE * pFile = fopen (path_.c_str() , "r");
if (pFile == NULL)
{
   perror ("Error opening file");
}
else
{
   char line [buffer_size]={0};
   size_t length=0;
   std::vector<unsigned> nodes;
   while ((line[length++] = fgetc (pFile)) != EOF )
   {
      printf("%d",line[length-1]);
      if (line[length-1] == '\r'||line[length-1] == '\n'
#ifdef __APPLE__
    ||line[length-1] == '$'
#endif
      )
{
   line[length-1]=0;
   unsigned number = 0;
   for(unsigned i=0;i<length;++i)
   {
      if(isdigit(line[i]))
   {
      number = number *10+line[i]-'0';
   }
else
   {
      nodes.push_back(number);
      number = 0;
   }
}
      memset(&line,0,buffer_size);
      length=0;
}
}
fclose (pFile);
```

I use `#ifdef __APPLE__` define, this code work perfectly on Linux, but on Mac OS X I now must read some symbol which defines end of line for my file/line. How can I get which symbol finished file, without this trick?

Comment: Question makes no sense - line endings on Mac OS X are not special and  certainly lines do not end in `$` - you should make your code robust enough to cope with any commonly found line ending (CR, LF, CR+LF).

Comment: If you see a [reference page for `fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) you will see that it returns an `int` and not a `char`. So as long as you don't treat the input as a string (which you don't seem to do) you should store it as `int` as well.

Comment: By the way, if you are using C++ (yes you are, using `std::vector` means you are using C++) then why not go C++ all the way with C++ file streams?

Comment: And I also recommend you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Joachim Pileborg plz write your comments in the answer, i think your answer is what i search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in C++:

```
unsigned number;
std::vector<unsigned> nodes;
std::ifstream file(path_.c_str());
while (file >> number)
    nodes.push_back(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations), OSX new line character is now `\n`, don't worry about that.

So, you don't have to make any Apple specific code, except if you want to support a Mac OS version <= **9**.